# Notepad++ Shortcut to Select Current Line

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut for Notepad++ that highlights the current line, regardless of where the cursor is? In Vim I would do this with ESC SHIFT+V.

I can do HOME then SHIFT+END, but the END and HOME keys are hard to reach and it has that extra step of going HOME first.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not that I know of, and the shortcut mapper or line operations menu doesn't have anything for selecting current line, so it might not exist. But you can triple click anywhere in the line and it will select the whole line even if the cursor is in the middle. Additionally, you can always record a macro to select the line and assign a shortcut to it.

Comment: Triple click is super helpful, and I just recorded a macro. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can record a macro with the outlined keys from your question. Then you can save the macro and assign a shortcut to it.

Answer (score 3):

I organize some materials about line operations via shortcut, hope it can help.

```
Shift+ [arrow]: select upper row or down row.
Ctrl+C  Copy
Ctrl+X  Cut
Ctrl+V  Paste
Ctrl+Z  Undo
Ctrl+Y  Redo
Ctrl+A  Select All
Ctrl+D  Duplicate Current Line
Ctrl+L  Delete Current Line
Ctrl+T  Switch the current line position with the previous line position
Ctrl+Shft+Up    Move current Line Up
Ctrl+Shft+Down  Move Current Line Down
Ctrl+Shft+BackSpace Delete to start of line
Ctrl+Shft+Delete    Delete to end of line
Ctrl+U  Convert to lower case
Ctrl+Shift+U Convert to upper case
Ctrl+Shft+T Copy current line to clipboard
```